# Проверка входящих значений Yii2

Tags: php, yii, валидация

Вопрос, изучая документацию по Yii не совсем разобрался с валидацией входящих данных:

```
class InsertForm extends Model
```

{

```
public $author;
public $message;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['author', 'validateValue'],
        ['message', 'validateValue'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @param $attribute
 * @param $params
 */
public function validateValue($attribute, $params)
{
    if ((strlen($attribute)<=5))
    {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Минимальная длинна поля 5 символов');
    }
}
```

}

Т.е. длина входящих значений должна начинаться от 5 символов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return [
  ['author', 'string', 'min' => 5, 'max' => 255, 'message'=>'Минимальная длинна поля 5 символов, не более 255'],
  ['message', 'string', 'min' => 5, 'max' => 255, 'message'=>'Минимальная длинна поля 5 символов, не более 255']
];
```

Comment: Благодарю, а что делать если приходит пустое значение?

Comment: Всё, разобрался, надо ещё добавить 'required' , ещё раз спасибо